# What's wrong with NVARCHAR and PATINDEX?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Please find this SQL function I wrote

### EDIT : Optimize function like it was suggested on the first case

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TL_ReplaceOldBrand]
(
    @string NVARCHAR(max),
    @BrandName NVARCHAR(50) = N'Brand',
    @BrandNameNew NVARCHAR(50) = N'NewBrand'
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS

BEGIN       
    DECLARE @ResultString NVARCHAR(max) = @string
    DECLARE @PossibleCharactersBegin NVARCHAR(100) = N'%[ ,.;:/?!-‘’''"(<>)' + Char(13) + Char(10) + ']'
    DECLARE @PossibleCharactersEnd NVARCHAR(100) = N'[ ,.;:/?!-‘’''"(<>)' + Char(13) + Char(10) + ']%'
    DECLARE @searchString NVARCHAR(100)

    --The brand name ONLY
    IF @ResultString = @BrandName
        SET @ResultString = REPLACE(@ResultString, @BrandName, @BrandNameNew)

    --The brand name at BEGINNING
    SET @searchString = N'' + @BrandName + @PossibleCharactersEnd
    WHILE PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString) > 0
    SET @ResultString = STUFF(@ResultString, PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString), LEN(@BrandName), @BrandNameNew)

    --The brand name BETWEEN words
    SET @searchString = N'' + @PossibleCharactersBegin + @BrandName + @PossibleCharactersEnd
    WHILE PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString) > 0
    SET @ResultString = STUFF(@ResultString, PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString) + 1, LEN(@BrandName), @BrandNameNew)

    --The brand name at the END
    SET @searchString = N'' + @PossibleCharactersBegin + @BrandName
    WHILE PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString) > 0
    SET @ResultString = STUFF(@ResultString, PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString) + 1, LEN(@BrandName), @BrandNameNew)

    RETURN @ResultString
END
```

Like this when I use it like this :

```
select dbo.TL_ReplaceOldBrand(N'I want to replace, Brand by NewBrand, in a long long text which have multiple Brand occurences.', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

The replacement didn't occured. But if I replaced, in the function defintion, all NVARCHAR by VARCHAR, it workds fine and replace *Brand* by *NewBrand* like I want.

Anyone can explain to me why ?

To answer to the question, why I want to use NVARCHAR instead VARCHAR, it is because the function is used on columns containing multiple language text with special characters like for Chinese, Thai or Korean

Comment: Since your first search/replace is using the most matchable string, what do you think the subsequent searches are going to do? I.e. if you've gone through a string replacing every `A` with `B`, why do you think you're going to get subsequent matches trying to find `A` with additional constraints on characters around it?

Comment: And once you're past that point, why not just use [`REPLACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186862.aspx) rather than manually finding/replacing occurrences.

Comment: REPLACE is good when you haven't multiple cases where the word can be presented. I can have ",Brand:" or " Brand," or "Brand-" or "Brand_".

Comment: But if you have a better idea to optimize this function I'm listening every solution. I'm not an expert of SQL Server, I'm listening day by day so I'm practicing ;-)

Comment: Maybe so, but your first Find and Replace is looking for "Brand" with nothing surrounding it, which matches all of those other cases also. It's doing exactly what `REPLACE` would do.

Comment: No absolutly not. The first case is the only word 'Brand' you have anything else. So it is not a word in a sentence but just the word that the major difference.

Comment: But in fact, I'm thinking between two answers ^^, you're right, I can use Replace by add constraint `@ResultString == @Brand`

Comment: I've edit my post. But that doesn't change anything about my issue :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104398/discussion-between-d4rktiger-and-damien-the-unbeliever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found an alternative answer to solve my issue

Please find the new function I wrote

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TL_ReplaceOldBrand]
(
    @string NVARCHAR(max),
    @BrandName VARCHAR(50) = N'Brand',
    @BrandNameNew VARCHAR(50) = N'NewBrand'
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS

BEGIN       
    DECLARE @ResultString VARCHAR(max) = @string
    DECLARE @NResultString NVARCHAR(max) = @string

    --REMARK: CHAR(13): Carriage Return
    --      : CHAR(10): Line Feed
    --      : CHAR(9) : Tabulation
    DECLARE @PossibleCharactersBegin VARCHAR(100) = N'%[ ,.;:/?!-‘’''"(<>)' + Char(13) + Char(10) + Char(9) + ']'
    DECLARE @PossibleCharactersEnd VARCHAR(100) = N'[ ,.;:/?!-‘’''"(<>)' + Char(13) + Char(10) + Char(9) + ']%'
    DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(100)

    DECLARE @index int = 0

    --The brand name ONLY
    IF @NResultString = @BrandName
    BEGIN
        SET @NResultString = REPLACE(@NResultString, @BrandName, @BrandNameNew)
        SET @ResultString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @NResultString)
    END

    --The brand name at BEGINNING
    SET @searchString = N'' + @BrandName + @PossibleCharactersEnd   
    SET @index = PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString)
    WHILE @index > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @NResultString = STUFF(@NResultString, @index, LEN(@BrandName), @BrandNameNew)
        SET @ResultString = @NResultString

        SET @index = PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString)
    END

    --The brand name BETWEEN words
    SET @searchString = N'' + @PossibleCharactersBegin + @BrandName + @PossibleCharactersEnd    
    SET @index = PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString)
    WHILE @index > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @NResultString = STUFF(@NResultString, @index + 1, LEN(@BrandName), @BrandNameNew)
        SET @ResultString = @NResultString

        SET @index = PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString)
    END

    --The brand name at the END
    SET @searchString = N'' + @PossibleCharactersBegin + @BrandName 
    SET @index = PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString)
    WHILE @index > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @NResultString = STUFF(@NResultString, @index + 1, LEN(@BrandName), @BrandNameNew)
        SET @ResultString = @NResultString

        SET @index = PATINDEX(@searchString, @ResultString)
    END

    RETURN @NResultString
END
```

I've used alternate variable to keep NVARCHAR format of the input string and work with patindex on its VARCHAR equivalent and its works fine.